# Regex replace a character or only replace one if repeating

Tags: java, regex, escaping, jsonb

I'm trying to write regex that will remove Backslash () character 
Replace "\" with "" , but using replace it will replace all the Backslash

However I do not want to replace all the Backslash ()

For example,

\"   TO "

\\\"  TO \"

\\n   TO \n

Here's sample data

**{\"data\":\"text\\\"textInsideQuote\\\"\"}**

What I expect

**{"data":"text\"textInsideQuote\"\"}**

The one that doesn't have any repeat should be replaced first, and then the one with repeat should be reduced to one.

Any idea on how I should achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The one that doesn't have any repeat should be replaced first, and then the one with repeat should be reduced to one.

I's not necessary to use two passes. It can be done with a single regex like so:

```
input.replaceAll("(\\\\)*\\\\", "$1")
```

- Any solitary backslash will be replaced by empty string
- Groups of repeating backslashes will be reduced to one single backslash

I hope I am interpreting your words correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is with my code where I double escape the json data.
For those who're interested in similar problem Patrick Parker's answer should work.

Thanks